# Mansfield toilet bubbing

Tags: plumbing

Mansfield toilet bubbing from secondary hole not main drain when flushed.  Splashing water upwards and outside bowl. I call it force hole

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what is your question?